# Is it possible to stop NSolve when it finds a single root

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of nonlinear algebraic equations with following property:
if $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7)$ is a root of the system, so any its permutation is another root as well. My system contains 7 equations, so **NSolve** tries to find all $7!$ solutions (and that's definitely impossible), but I need only one of them.

How can I stop **NSolve** after finding a single root.

Comment: Try `FindRoot` instead?

Comment: `FindInstance` maybe?

Comment: If you post the system here, maybe we can suggest a neater approach than just blindly using `NSolve[]` that won't exploit the symmetry.

Comment: Try `WhenEvent`

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess that it's a symmetric polynomial system.  Since there are exactly 7! solutions, it follows that it would be a linear system in the symmetric polynomials.  If so, here is a way to proceed.

We set up the solution to the general symmetric polynomial system
$$
s(x) = a
$$
where $x = (x_1,\dots,x_7)$ and $s=(s_1,\dots,s_7)$ are the symmetric polynomials of degrees 1 through 7, and the $a=(a_1,\dots,a_7)$ are constants.  `Reduce` solves this rather quickly with a cylindrical algebraic decomposition that allows us to use back-substitution and drop all but the first solution.

Then, for a random symmetric system, we convert it to a linear system in the symmetric polynomials by eliminating $x_i$ in terms of $s_i$ (using `SymmetricReduction` as J.M. points out).  We can then apply the general solution described above.

```
Clear[x, s];
nvars = 7;
vars = Array[x, nvars];
sbasis = Table[SymmetricPolynomial[i, vars], {i, 0, nvars}];
spolys = Array[s,           (* represents the value a_i of the symmetric poly s_i *)
  nvars + 1,
  {0, nvars}];
sys0 = Table[-s[i] + SymmetricPolynomial[i, vars], {i, nvars}];    (* general system *)
sys1 = Reduce[Thread[sys0 == 0], vars] /. And -> List /. (* solve the general system *)
    Or -> First@*List; // AbsoluteTiming   (* picks first solution for each variable *)
solFN[s0_] := Fold[       (* compose sol. s0 to the linear system with the gen. sol. *)
  Join[#1, #2 /. #1] &, ToRules /@ sys1 /. s0];
(*  {0.09048, Null}  -- Time to solve general system  *)
```

It turns out that `solFN` finds the final solution much faster by first applying the numeric solution `s0` than it takes to completely solve the general system:

```
sol1 = Fold[
    Join[#1, #2 /. #1] &, ToRules /@ sys1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {44.6646, Null}  *)
```

**Example**

```
SeedRandom[0];
exSys = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {nvars, nvars + 1}].sbasis;

(s0 = First@ Solve[
       First@SymmetricReduction[#, vars, Rest@spolys] == 0,
       Rest@spolys];
 exSol = solFN[s0, sys1];) // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.174598, Null}  *)
```

Including the time to solve the general system, the total time is just over a 1/4 sec.
Note that `exSol` is the exact solution.  Below is a numeric approximation and a check of the residuals:

```
MapAt[N, exSol, {All, 2}]
(*
  {x[1] -> 0.963681, x[2] -> -0.664128 - 0.585071 I, 
   x[3] -> -0.664128 + 0.585071 I, x[4] -> 0.131469 + 1.19911 I, 
   x[5] -> 0.131469 - 1.19911 I, x[6] -> 0.281166 + 0.596566 I, 
   x[7] -> 0.281166 - 0.596566 I}
*)

exSys /. %
(*
  {4.44089*10^-15 + 2.27596*10^-15 I, 1.77636*10^-15 - 6.17562*10^-16 I,
   3.77476*10^-15 + 1.11022*10^-15 I, 1.77636*10^-15 + 1.11022*10^-15 I,
   0. + 5.55112*10^-17 I, -2.44249*10^-15 - 2.66454*10^-15 I, 
   1.77636*10^-15 + 2.22045*10^-16 I}
*)
```

Comment: Alternatively, one might consider applying `SymmetricReduction[]` with its third argument to the components of the system, and then using Newton-Girard afterwards.

Comment: @J.M. I thought I tried that in this approach, but I must have goofed.